# How can I specify a specific log file to write to from a Sitecore Powershell script?

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have some scripts where I'd like to separate their log output from the standard Sitecore Powershell log (SPE.log).

Is there a parameter which I can use on `Write-Log` to output to a named log file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot. It doesn't support anything like that.

Here is a documentation of [Write-Log](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/write-log) cmldet.

If you are interested you can see how it is implemented:

- [WriteLogCommand.cs](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/blob/master/Cognifide.PowerShell/Commandlets/Diagnostics/WriteLogCommand.cs)
- [PowerShellLog.cs](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/blob/master/Cognifide.PowerShell/Core/Diagnostics/PowerShellLog.cs)

SPE jsut defines it own log4net appender, see configuration here [Cognifide.PowerShell.config](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/blob/master/Cognifide.PowerShell/App_Config/Include/Cognifide.PowerShell.config) (serach for `PowerShellExtensionsFileAppender`)

You would have to implement your own solution with dynamic appenders.

This might give you an idea of where to start: [How to add log4net appender in runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833362/how-to-add-log4net-appender-in-runtime)

Answer (score 6):

Chiming in here to provide a work-around.

Remember: You can always invoke C# directly from Powershell.

For instance, this is valid powershell: `[Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log]::Info("Test", "MyCustomLogger");`

Which assumes that you have something like this logger set up in MyApp.Logging.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:x="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
      <appender name="MyCustomLoggerAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
        <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/MyCustomLogger.log.{date}.txt" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />
        </layout>
      </appender>
      <logger name="MyCustomLogger" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="MyCustomLoggerAppender" />
      </logger>
    </log4net>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```